# Why are some packages unfindable in new non-LTS releases of Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, repository, netbeans

Well, simply put I've installed the new Ubuntu 15.04 but it does not contain my favourite Netbeans IDE in its repository. I certainly did run `sudo apt-get update`. Why is this so? Does this mean that the Ubuntu package managing people has decided not to include Netbeans in the repository of future Ubuntu releases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like netbeans is not ready for vivid as of now. You can however, install it by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/netbeans/netbeans_7.0.1+dfsg1-5ubuntu2_all.deb
sudo gdebi netbeans_7.0.1+dfsg1-5ubuntu2_all.deb
```

Review any changes before confirming to accept.

You will have to keep up on any security updates or newer versions untill the vivid version is released. These versions can be found here http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=utopic&keywords=netbeans

done